# Is it necessary to run jstack -F as root (on linux) and if so why?

Tags: java, jvm, jstack

Is it necessary to run jstack -F as root (on linux) and if so why?

When trying to jstack -F my **own** processes I get the following error.

Error attaching to process: sun.jvm.hotspot.debugger.DebuggerException: Can't attach to the process

jstack -F works fine if I run it with sudo.

Answer (score 14):

It's because `jstack -F` uses the `ptrace(2)` system call to try and access the JVM data, which fails if you don't have the rights:

```
$ strace -e all -f jstack -F 26846
...
[pid 27653] ptrace(PTRACE_ATTACH, 26846, 0, 0) = -1 EPERM (Operation not permitted)
...
```

From the [`ptrace(2)` man](http://linux.die.net/man/2/ptrace):

> ```
> EPERM  The specified process cannot be traced. This could be because the parent
>        has insufficient privileges (the required capability is CAP_SYS_PTRACE);
>        unprivileged  processes  cannot trace processes that they cannot send
>        signals to or those running set-user-ID/set-group-ID programs, for obvious
>        reasons.  Alternatively, the process may already be being traced, or be
>        init(8) (PID 1).
> ```

See also [capabilities(7)](http://linux.die.net/man/7/capabilities). Using `sudo`, you get root's capabilities, which include `CAP_SYS_PTRACE`.